# SparseArray size() returns 0

Tags: android, sparse-matrix

I'm having a problem with a `SparseArray` when calling the `size()` method, specifically it returns 0 also if I've just added some elements. This is the first time I'm having this kind of (apparently stupid) problem.

I'm in an AsyncTask's `doInBackground` method:

```
SparseArray<MyPojoClass> myArray = new SparseArray<>();

// some HttpURLConnection stuffs
// ...

while (/*...reading from the urlConnection's input stream ...*/) {
    MyPojoClass myObject = new MyPojoClass(something);
    myArray.put(atag, myObject);
}

// close the urlConnection
// ...

// THE PROBLEM!
if (myArray.size() == 0)
    return null;
return myArray;
```

That is approximately the important part of the `doInBackground`. I noticed that, if I put a breakpoint on the size check it always return the right size and the app works perfectly; if I let the app going without breakpoints it sometimes fails on that check.

I did not found other problems related with the `SparseArray` class. Before you ask it, nobody else (other threads) writes or reads the same SparseArray. The thread which creates and works on it is a secondary one, but this should not be the problem.

Comment: Did you do something async in `while` block ?

Comment: Absolutely no. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/blob/master/youtubeExtractor/src/main/java/at/huber/youtubeExtractor/YouTubeExtractor.java) (it is not mine). The method is getStreamUrls which is called in a doInBackground method. The problem is on the check `ytFiles.size()`

Comment: Maybe `atag` is `null`?

Comment: Did you find out the problem? Running into the same issue right now

Comment: Unfortunately not. This problem is into a library which I modified to always return the array, without that check... I would like to fix it to suggest the modification...